# Angular 5 animations on list with delay

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I want to add a rotation animation to a list of images, but I can't do it. I can do a global rotation, but I would like to offset these animations with a delay. The trigger `list`make the good animation, but only on start. The list is updated when the component data is updated.

Thank you.

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-totem',
  templateUrl: './totem.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./totem.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('totem', [
      transition('* => *', [
        query(':self',
          stagger('70ms', [
            style({ transform: 'rotateY(-180deg)' }),
            animate('800ms ease-in-out')
          ])
        )
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('list', [
      transition('* => *', [
        query('.totem',
          stagger('70ms', [
            style({ transform: 'rotateY(-180deg)' }),
            animate('800ms ease-in-out')
          ])
        )
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Component.html

```
<div class="totems" #totems [@list]="items.length">
  <div class="totem" *ngFor=" let item of items" @totem>
    <div class="front" [style.background-image]="'url(' + item.front.url + ')'"></div>
    <div class="back" [style.background-image]="'url(' + item.back.url + ')'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a small StackBlitz example to be able to help more easily ?

Answer (score 2):

you are close.  you are correct when you create a trigger @totem

but your animation should be

```
trigger('totem', [
  transition(':enter', [
    query('*', [
      style({ transform: 'rotateY(-180deg)' }),
      stagger(70, [
        animate('800ms ease-in-out', style('*'))
      ]), { delay: 200 }
    ])
])
```

as seen in [YearofMoo New Wave of Animation Features](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html)

they have a section devoted to ngFor.   the KEY point is :enter  is what the ngFor wants  that way when the ngFor renders, it does the animation, and if you filter the ngFor it will always hit that ":enter" state with new items.  (you can also do a :leave animation as well).

Also if you want to put a delay, its , { delay: 200 } after your animate line